# SQL Server version

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014

I´m trying to run an SSIS 2013 Package in SQL Server 2014 but i keep getting the error "package migration from version 8 to version 6 failed with error".

So i ckecked the vertion in SQL Server 2014 using a T-SQL query:

SELECT @@VERSION

and i got:

"Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3153.0 (X64) 
    Jul 22 2014 15:26:36 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
"

The response for this query should be SQL Server 2014, right?

What should i do to alter this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with running the package. I ran into the same error. What happened was that the package was deployed to an Integration services server (version 2012) using the 2014 IS wizard (or visual studio 2013 SSDT)... SSIS and Visual Studio 2013 will not work for SQL Server 2012. There are several Microsoft connect tickets for this but I doubt any of them will get fixed.

Answer (score 0):

SSIS versions are not backwards compatible.
VS 2013 is used for SQL Server 2014, VS 2010/12 is used for SQL Server 2012.

So the SSIS modules created with VS2013 are only compatible to SQL Server 2014.
Older SQL Server versions (2012, 2008...) can not handle them.